# How many times "-" at beginning of string (before alphabet letter)

Tags: php, string, count, substr, find-occurrences

I'm having trouble knowing how many times that the `-` character is in **front** of my string.

Some examples:

```
$string = "-Lorem Ipsum";   // 1
$string = "--Lorem Ipsum";  // 2
$string = "---Lorem Ipsum"; // 3
$string = "--Lorem-Ipsum";  // 2
```

But how can I find this? I know you can search the number of occurrences of a character in a string. But I want the number of `-` characters before an alphabet letter. Not all the sequences (see last example).

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the old school trick of using a string as an array here as such:

```
$search="-";
$i=0;
while($string[$i]==$search)
{
    $i++;
}
echo "Found $i instances at the start of the string.";
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `ltrim()` and `strlen()`

```
echo strlen($string) - strlen(ltrim($string, "-"));
```

See [example at eval.in](https://eval.in/195595)

Answer (score 0):

it would also work -

```
preg_match('/(?!-)/', $string, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

`$match` - the position of any character but `-` which is indeed the count of `-`.